# data coming from arduino to python (raspberryPi) invalid literal error

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have seen this invalid literal error meaning the data in the int() on the python side isn't a base 10 digit like its expecting.  I get that, but on the arduino side I send it across serial with:

```
void loop()
{
  temperature = bmp085GetTemperature(bmp085ReadUT());
  pressure = bmp085GetPressure(bmp085ReadUP());
  Serial.println(temperature, DEC);  //fails on python side, outputs a 240 usually
  delay(50);
  Serial.println(pressure, DEC); //pa
  delay(1000);
}
```

and on the python side I pick it up with this:

```
while True:
     if(serialFromArduino.inWaiting() > 0):
          input = serialFromArduino.readline().rstrip()
          print(input)
          inputAsInteger =int(input)   #FAILS
          print("done")
```

Even did an rstrip to make sure i get rid of any \t\r\n etc.

So I am puzzled as to why the constant

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/pythoncode $ python serialtest.py
Running
240
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "serialtest.py", line 18, in <module>
   inputAsInteger =int(input)
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Just not sure what I am missing?  New to python though so its feasible its something incredibly stupid I am doing.

Comment: Just so you know exactly what you're dealing with, on the debug print, try this: `print(input.encode('hex'))`

Comment: awesome!  okay didnt know I had that option, ran again got a bazillion 0's and it ends in: 0323430  is this an ascii value?  before the previous number is a count of 2951 0s

Comment: Yes, `00 32 34 30` is (null-byte) '2' '4' '0'. So your data is being prepended with a bunch of null characters. See my answer for how to remove them. I'm not sure why it's happening though. What is `serialFromArduino`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your data has a bunch of null bytes (ASCII code 0x00). You'll want to remove them with `strip('\x00')`.  By default [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) only removes whitspace, which doesn't include null bytes. So we specify what bytes to remove manually.

```
 if(serialFromArduino.inWaiting() > 0):
      input = serialFromArduino.readline().strip().strip('\x00')      # <--
      print(input)
      inputAsInteger = int(input)
      print("done")
```

Perhaps the better solution is to identify *where* the null bytes are coming from and prevent this huge waste of serial bandwidth from happening.

PS. The reason the error message was so unhelpful here:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Is probably because they are string formatting the invalid literal into their error message. However, some library call along the way is interpreting the null byte as a null-terminator and not printing the rest of the string.

Comment: If i had to guess its in the calls to the library im using i didn't write:  ` temperature = bmp085GetTemperature(bmp085ReadUT());
  pressure = bmp085GetPressure(bmp085ReadUP());`

Comment: p.s. stripped out the bytes using that strip \x00 and it printed same thing in the hex call

Comment: I think you realize it, but `strip()` *returns* the modified string; it doesn't modify it in-place.

Comment: ha so didn't realize, its working now :) woo hoo thanks! now my pachube library is woefully old it seems, thats for tomorrow.  awesome guys thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your input received an empty line `''` and you try to convert it to an integer.

You should cautiously process the external input at `input = serialFromArduino.readline()`. If it is not a proper integer (like, empty line or some noise) you program will crash. You should, for example:

```
try:
    input = serialFromArduino.readline().rstrip()
except ValueError:
    raise InputError('got bad value {}'.format(input))
```